# Get ID from database of a checked checkbox which is retrieved from database?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

```
<?php
$conn=get_dbconnect();
$sql="select name from states";
$rs = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);//odbc_exec($conn,$sql);
if(mysqli_num_rows($rs) > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs)) {
      echo "<input type='checkbox' name='states' value='".$row['name']."'; /> ".$row['name'];  
    } 
}
mysqli_close($conn); 
?>

<input type="submit" onclick="check('states')"> ?>
```

This is the code to fetch the values of state from database. How to get the value of auto incremented id of each state which is inside database using JavaScript. After getting the id I want to add that value to another SQL table.

Comment: you have not selected the `ID` of each state - only the name

Comment: What ID are you talking about? your <input> doesnt contain any id's

Comment: i am taking about the id inside database for each state

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use a for loop with some conditions:

```
var allInputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input"), arr = [];
for (var i = 0, max = allInputs.length; i < max; i++){
    if (allInputs[i].type === 'checkbox' && allInputs[i].checked){
       arr.push(allInputs[i].value); // <----will push the checked one's values only
    }
}
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

use this .

```
      <input type='checkbox' name='states[]' value='".$row['id']."' id="st"/>               ".$row['name'];
```

and get like this . hope it will help .

```
  if ($("#st").prop('checked')) 
  {
    //blah blah
     alert($("#st").val());
  }
```

Comment: the html generated after using your answer will be invalid.. also your code may not work

Comment: @SagarGuhe thanks for the advise can you post this answer i also want to know .

Comment: I will get you hints instead: 1) `id="st"` => `id='st".$i."'` also notice syntax 2) `if ($("#st").prop('checked'))` => `if ($(elem).prop('checked'))` if you use `.each()` 3) `alert($("#st").val());` => `alert($(elem).attr('id'));`... However generating ids like this is recommended or not I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to put all the values in an array, after that you can send it to the SQL Database.

```
<?php
$conn=get_dbconnect();
$sql="select name from states";
$rs = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);//odbc_exec($conn,$sql);
$stateIds = array();
$cBoxId = 0;
if(mysqli_num_rows($rs) > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs)) {
      $cBoxId = $cBoxId + 1;
      echo "<input type='checkbox' id='".$cBoxId."' name='states' value='".$row['name']."'; /> ".$row['name'];  
      $stateIds[] = $cBoxId;
    } 
}
mysqli_close($conn); 
?>

<input type="submit" onclick="check('states')"> ?>
```